# Magical Record MR_createEntity() returns nil object, using swift

Tags: ios, swift, magicalrecord

The following returns nil

```
let entity = Data.MR_createEntity()
```

I've initialized Magical record as follows and the log indicates positive output.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MagicalRecord.setLoggingLevel(MagicalRecordLoggingLevel.Debug)
    MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed("proff")

    context = NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed step of creating the model file.
More of a core data thing than a magical record thing.
once I created that, then generated the swift code the create worked.